# R programming: cv.lm with NAs in a categorical column

Tags: r, na, lm, cross-validation

I want to learn a lm for a data frame using `cv.lm` function from DAAG library. I tried the next code (obviously this is a toy example for this question):

```
> my data
x    y z
1    a  3.0 1
2    a 10.5 2
3    b 10.4 3
4    b  8.3 4
5    c 11.8 5
6 <NA> 11.6 6

> cv.lm(m, y ~ ., m=3)
```

The problem is that I found that having NAs in a categorical column (a factor) yield the next error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , ynam, value = c(3, 10.5, 10.4, 8.3,  :
replacement has 5 rows, data has 6
```

I found it by reducing mydata to only two columns (the factor, and the y).

Is is there a way to handle NA in cv.lm?

`lm` function does handle it w/o problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reproduce the `lm` treatment of NAs using `na.omit`.

So: `cv.lm(data=na.omit(m), y ~ ., m=3)`